# Is asking about firsts or existence of a trope an identification question?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by this question:
[If aliens visited Earth, and used the cliche "take me to your leader" or a variation of it, why is it always the POTUS?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89684/if-aliens-visited-earth-and-used-the-cliche-take-me-to-your-leader-or-a-varia)

I don't believe there is any movie where aliens ask to be taken to a leader (in any form of the question) **except as a joke**. So I thought I might ask,

> Except as a joke, is there any movie where aliens ask to be "taken to a leader" or put in touch with an authority?

I know questions about the first time something was done have been, and seem to still be, on-topic. Is asking for existence of a movie with a specific trope too much like an identification question, or is it on topic?

Or is it on topic but too broad?

Comment: It would be on topic using the [tag:first-appearance] tag but since it's a **very old** trope it might be realy hard to nail down.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_me_to_your_leader_(phrase)

Comment: That said, Klaatu said in 1951 - *"I want to meet with representatives                     from all the nations of the Earth."*

Comment: @Paulie_D I had read the Wikipedia article, which only seems to cite humorous uses. But it seems like you have answered my question by pointing out the existence of the first-appearance tag. Thanks!